# how to display twitter user feed in rails with twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-gem

Im using the twitter gem for rails to try and show 3 statuses from my twitter feed. I'm doing everything as per the documentation but its not displaying anything in my view.

In my application controller I've got this down:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
 config.consumer_key        = "***********"
  config.consumer_secret     = "***********"
  config.access_token        = "***********"
  config.access_token_secret = "***********" 

 end



def client.get_all_tweets(user)
    options = {:count => 3, :include_rts => true}
      user_timeline(user, options)
  end


  @tweet_news = client.get_all_tweets("tezzataz")
```

Then in my view I have simply put:

```
<% @tweet_news %>
```

I don't get any errors but I have nothing showing in my view. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try <% @tweet_news.each do |tweet| %> <%= tweet.text %> <% end %> in your view.

Comment: comes up with an undefined method error

Comment: Here's a simple example setup. https://github.com/O-I/twitter_example

Answer (score 0):

Used this for same purpose.

```
<ul>
  <% @tweet_news.each do |f| %>
    <li>
      <%= f.text%>
      <span><%= time_ago_in_words(f.created_at) %> ago</span>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
require 'twitter'

class TweetController < ApplicationController
  def index
    client = TweetController.create_client
    begin
      @tweets = get_tweets(client)
    rescue => e
      #TODO: render 404 with the error
       puts "Error : #{e.to_s}"
    end
  end

  private
  def get_tweets(client, userName)
    client.user_timeline(userName, :count => 200)
  end
end
```

View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="timeline">
            <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
                    <div class="timeline-image">
                        <!-- Show user avatar (profile pic)-->
                        <img class="img-circle" src= '<%= image_path(tweet.user.profile_image_url_https.to_s.gsub('_normal','')) %>' alt="" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <!-- Show user name -->
                            <h4> <%= tweet.user.name %></h4>
                            <h4 class="subheading"> <%= "@#{tweet.user.screen_name}"  %> </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p class="text-muted"> <%= tweet.text%> </p>
                            <i class="fa fa-retweet"> <%= tweet.retweet_count %> </i>
                            <i class="fa fa-heart"> <%= tweet.favorite_count %> </i>                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```